# How to Redirect to an URL in A Command line Inteface (CLI)

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I Was Trying to make a redirection to an URL in A CLI Using nodejs.
How Can i do this? I Tried Using request, But i Dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do?
I think you can use:
curl -v -L [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Or if you can be more specific...